# Color underneath website footer

Tags: html, css, footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

I've been helping a guy with the website [here](http://saveamillioncampaign.com/). If you'll notice, the on some pages (like [this](http://saveamillioncampaign.com/leave-a-testimonial/)) the footer has some large whitespace underneath it, because the page is short.

How can we get the black in the footer to extend all the way down regardless of page height (and window/browser height?)

note: We don't want a sticky footer

Comment: read the note: I don't want a "sticky footer". I want the black to extend all the way to the bottom of the window.

Comment: unless the footer has to be scrolled to of course, then I want the height to remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any reliable method to have the footer extend to the bottom of the page. However, to get the effect you desire, you could do the following:

- Apply black background to body
- Apply white background to #primary
- Swap top margin of footer for bottom padding on #primary

Answer (score 1):

Set the background-color of the HTML element:

```
html { background-color: #000 }
```